# trying to integrate Community Engine into my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

## error

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "multi_json":
  In Gemfile:
    community_engine (>= 0) ruby depends on
      multi_json (~> 1.0.0) ruby

    uglifier (>= 1.0.3) ruby depends on
      multi_json (1.3.6)
```

## Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'json'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'community_engine', :github => 'bborn/communityengine', :branch => 'rails3'
```

## doubt

always gives the same error despite of following all the instructions in the README FILE of the community engine

Comment: Try doing a `bundle update community_engine`.

Comment: @user1437670, I suggest you to increase your acceptance percentage by accpeting the answers that helped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `gem "multi_json"` in Gemfile

delete the Gemfile.lock file

And then run `bundle install`

This helped me to overcome the above error.